# How do I resolve the incompatible types in my code

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have to implement my own `ArrayList` class using generics for a java assignment. For some reason I'm getting an incompatible type error and I have failed in my attempt to find help elsewhere.

Here is my code followed by the exact error:

```
public <E> boolean addItem ( E item ) 
{           
    if ( numElements == list.length ) {             
        enlarge();
        list [numElements] = item;
        numElements ++;
        return true;
    } else {                
        list [numElements] = item;
        numElements ++;
        return true;
    }
}
```

the Error:

```
ArrayList.java:91: error: incompatible types
                        list [numElements] = item;
                                             ^(points at item)
  required: E#2
  found:    E#1
  where E#1,E#2 are type-variables:
    E#1 extends Object declared in method <E#1>addItem(E#1)
    E#2 extends hasKey declared in class ArrayList
```

I apologize if this has been answered elsewhere, I'm just not sure what I should be searching for to find the answer I need.

Comment: what are the types of `list` and `item`?

Comment: Can we have your full class code please? It'll make it a lot easier

Comment: Please post an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you can

Comment: There isn't a single type in the code you posted. How do you expect us to help?

Comment: That's about as thorough and exhaustive an error-message as I have seen in a good long while. Clearly, one is an Object, the other is an ArrayList.

Comment: This was my first time using this site as an actual poster, I'll take this as a lesson learned if I need to post again. Thank you to those that responded so quickly and I apologize once again.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your error you have two type variables called E, one in the class level and one in the method `addItem`. You should simply remove the type parameter from the `addItem` method.

Change

```
public <E> boolean addItem (E item)
```

to

```
public boolean addItem (E item)
```

The same applies to any other non-static methods of your class having a generic type parameter which represents the `ArrayList` member type. They should all use the generic type parameter declared in the class level.

Comment: or `<T extends E> boolean addItem(T item)`